# Ajax success object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to validate the form using AJAX. This is what I've done so far:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var user = username.value;
  var pass = password.value;

  if (user != '' && pass != '') {
    $('#login').html('Proccessing...');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'login.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        username: user,
        password: pass
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == 'success') {
          window.location.href = 'admin.php';
        } else {
          $('.login_message').html('Incorrect Credentails');
          $('#login').html('Login');
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.login_message').html('Fill All Fields');
    $('#login').html('Login');
  }
})
```

and it seems like `response` doesn't return `success`. Below is the login.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
$password = $username = '';
$_SESSION['user'] = $_SESSION['error'] = '';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        include_once('db.php');
        $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

        $password = md5($password);
        echo 'username: ' . $username . ' and ' . ' password: ' . $password;
        $sql   = "select * from users where username = '" . $username . "' limit 1";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($query) {
            $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $dbpass = $row['password'];
            if ($password == $dbpass) {
                ;
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                header('Location: admin.php');
            } else {
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Wrong username or password!';
            }
        } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

If it happens you have found the solution, please explain to me how you find the solution and what I've done wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: your `login.php` is responsible for "success" as response or not!

Comment: You would need to show your `login.php` code too.

Comment: add `console.log(response)` to know your server response

Comment: `response` is an object. Until you send `success` string from server end, it will never equal to `success`. Better paste your `login.php` code too.

Comment: @baao I've tried using `response.data` still it does nothing

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I've edited the post and posted the login.php.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Using `strip_tags()` is _far_ from a safe way to escape data.

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You're echoing a lot in your file, but _none_ of it is `'success'`, though. so the response will never be `response == 'success'`. You also echo stuff before trying to set header location. That will result in a "Headers already sent" error.

Comment: Two problems `echo` will return values to jQuery, it you cannot echo multiple values. Also `$_POST['error' ]` doesn't seem to be set. Read my answer, I also explain how to write a PHP target file for AJAX.

Comment: @M_Magz see my answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the enlightenment. So what are suggesting me to do?

Comment: did you read all answers?

Answer (score 0):

## Returning values from PHP back to JS

When using AJAX, I believe if you do `echo` in the PHP target file (here `login.php`) it will act as a `return`. Therefore the code after a `echo` will not run as you might expect.

Also in your code you have: `echo $_SESSION['error'] = '';`

Use `==` to compare two object, `=` is the [assignment operator](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp).

---

## Retrieving AJAX data in PHP file

The use of the `ajax()` method from jQuery in your code looks correct to me. So when the call is made the information is sent asynchronously to the server. More precisely it will send the parameters to the PHP file you've specified in the ajax object properties: `login.php`.

In `login.php` you can access your passed parameters in the `$_POST` array.

You would have the following:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// process information...
$state = 'success'

// now you can return a JSON object back to your page
// I strongly recommend using a PHP array and converting it to JSON
// this way it's very easy to access it back with JS

$response = array(state=$state)
echo json_encode($response);
```

And back in your jQuery code you access the state value with `response.state`

```
if(response.state == 'success') {
  alert('It is a succcess!');
}
```

---

## Debugging PHP target files

Now you generally have problems in the code in this PHP files. And it's not an easy thing to debug it. So the way I proceed is: I set the parameters in stone in `login.php` for instance:

```
$username = 'usernameTest'; // $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = 'passwordTest'; // $password = $_POST['password'];
```

Then I would open the PHP file in a browser and run it do see if it echoes the object and if there are any bugs.

Then you can put back `$username = $_POST['username'];` and `$password = $_POST['password'];`.

---

## Actual code

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) {
    include_once('db.php');

    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password);

    $sql   = "select * from users where username = '" . $username . "' limit 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($query) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      $dbpass = $row['password'];

        if ($password == $dbpass) {
           $state = 'success';
        } else {
           $state = 'failed';
        }

    } else {
      echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

---

## Warning `mysql()`, `md5()` and SQL injections

> - Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.
> - You are wide open to SQL Injections and should really use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating your queries. Using `strip_tags()` is far from a safe way to escape data.
> - Don't use `md5()` for password hashing. It's very insecure. Use PHP's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the `password_compat` library to get the same functionality.
>
> - [Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson)

Comment: Actually, the code `echo $_SESSION['error'] = '';` won't throw an error at all. It will just echo an empty string.

Comment: Yes it depends on the server used, I got the error message from an online PHP sandbox. And that's why it's so crucial to test PHP target files independently without AJAX.

Comment: That's probably because online php-sandboxes usually don't have sessions. Otherwise, doing stuff like: `echo $var1 = '';` is the same as `$var1 = $var2 = ''` which is totally valid in PHP. I've never heard that it depends on the server.

Comment: I have edited my post, a lot of stuff added in. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is `ajax` request,we need to send some response from server. As you did in your question check `if(response=='success')`. To do that, you need to send `success` to your client. If everything is ok (data send to server and query) then in your `login.php` edit this line

```
if($password == $dbpass) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
     //comment this line
    //header('Location: admin.php');
    echo "success";
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Wrong username or password!';
}
```

Here I put one line code `echo "success";` and I believe this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I've tried this but still it does not work. What I really want to do is validate the form with the use of ajax

Comment: @M_Magz, If you want to validate your form only, then why would you sent request to server just to validate. You can do it from client side with javascript.Your provided code doesn't show any validation part,rather show user login process.